# ERROR: Could not determine java version from '15.0.2'

Tags: java, gradle, gradlew, minecraft-forge

Hey so I was trying to run the command `./gradlew setupDecompWorkspace` on the windows powershell and it gave me an error as shown in the image. I also checked to see what version of gradle I was using and it said `gradle-2.7-bin.zip` inside the `gradle-wrapper.properties` and I tried upgrading the version via powershell using a command but the term gradle is not recognized. Please help me solve this issue since i need to do this for forge api.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Gradle 2.7 is an ancient version of Gradle from 2015. Java 15.x did not exist at that time. This version of Gradle does not know about it.

I think you might have more success when you try to run this build with Java 8.

Comment: Is there any way i could update gradle to it's latest version?

Comment: In theory, yes... But there's a good chance you will need to modifiy the build to get it to work,. Quite a few things changed between 2.7 and 6.8.3. This is easier to do when you start from a runnable state. You could use https://github.com/jenv/jenv to manage multiple java installations on your machine easily.